# Writing a function in server.js and calling it from client side (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I want to write a function in server.js.

```
    export const doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

So here, I need to get email and password from the client side. When I try to export the function in server.js and use it in client side. I got an error that said

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../server/products which fall outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

Is there anyway I can call a function from server side?

Comment: You need to setup API endpoints for this. Lookup how to create a REST API with nodejs to communicate between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the file structure, it's difficult to give a definitive answer, although it would seem that that your application is expecting `src/` to be your root directory and the relative path is beyond that.

Comment: guesses should go into the comment section.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So there is no way to export a function from server side?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Without access to my computer, I was unable to test, and yes, it ought to be a comment on this occasion.